# Linker command failed with exit code Error occurs after re-opening project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Everytime I close my project and re-open, this error occurs:

> (null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have added XMPPFramework into my project, to solve this issue I have to delete the Framework file from the project and add them again.

For reference I have added two Images:

[image: Libraries]

[image: Error Log]

I am using latest XMPP Framework and Xcode 6.2.

Comment: Yes I Did, also the empty folders from the project folder too.

Comment: I did that too...I'll revert back to you after implementing your answer. :)